# Compare two tables

Tags: r, if-statement

What is the easiest way and the fastest way to compare dataframes.
Input:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                  A = c(1, 2, 3, NA),
                  B = c(1, 2, NA, NA))
> df1
  ID  A  B
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3 NA
4  4 NA NA

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                  A = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                  B = c(1, 2, 3, NA))
> df2
  ID A  B
1  1 1  1
2  2 2  2
3  3 3  3
4  4 4 NA
```

I assume that data frames have the same amount of rows and columns.
The output data frame should contain:

1. Column ID with values from df1 or df2 - (doesn't mather if from df1 or df2 because they are the same.
2. In columns A and B shoud be value from df2 if content of cell from df1 is different than in df2, or NA if values are the same.

I can use for and iterate for every row and column but it is not elegant solution.
Is it better?

I tried:

```
result = apply(ifelse(df1[,] == df2[,], NA, df2[,])
```

but doesn't work.

The output df should look like this:

```
result <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                  A = c(NA, NA, NA, 4),
                  B = c(NA, NA, 3, NA)) 

> result
  ID  A  B
1  1 NA NA
2  2 NA NA
3  3 NA  3
4  4  4 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare using `==` and overwrite the matches with `NA` in `df2`:

```
df2[-1][df1[-1] == df2[-1]] <- NA
df2
#  ID  A  B
#1  1 NA NA
#2  2 NA NA
#3  3 NA  3
#4  4  4 NA
```

Comment: Thanks for very fast responce. I even thouht that solution will be such easy.
I assume that -1 say to exclude first column. How to make it if there will be second column ID2, which also shouls have always value like column ID?

Comment: To exclude the first two columns use `df1[-1:-2]`, or only the second `df[-2]`.